# Refreshing access token only when necessary

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Following a [previous question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178144/authenticating-a-user-without-querying-a-particular-google-service%20previous%20question%20posted%20here), I'm trying to use the Calendar service from a server app.

I manage the authentication flow "myself" and store the user's access token and refresh token in the DB. Now I think I can use the method showed in the .NET client's samples in order to use the `CalendarService`. But I'm still wondering what would be the best implementation of the `IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(WebServerClient client)` method in order to request a refresh of the access token only when it's required. My current, naive implementation refreshes the token every time:

```
private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(WebServerClient client)
{
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { "profile", CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
    state.AccessToken = _accessToken;
    state.RefreshToken = _refreshToken;

    client.RefreshToken(state);

    return state;
}
```

... but I'm sure there's a smarter way to do this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of flows you can use, depending on the need for performance v. bandwidth, length of sessions, etc.

1. You can do no proactive refresh, let the transaction fail 401, then get a new token and retry the transaction. Efficient use of bandwidth and processing, but causes a delay to the transaction.
2. You can note the expiration time of the token, and create a timer task to refresh the token say 1 minute before it's due to expire. Gives best performance because there is always a token available, but consumes bandwidth and processing time.
3. Before you try the transaction, check the token timeout. If it's
   expired, get a new one, then submit the transaction. If it has < 5
   minutes to live, use it and after the transaction is complete,
   refresh the token ready for next time. This gives (for my use case at least) the best balance between efficient transactions and not doing too many redundant refreshes.

Comment: Right. I was wondering if the .NET client library could do your first case automagically, but the lack of documentation makes it a guessing game. I'll store the access token expiration date in DB and trigger the refresh on a per-request basis if we're near the expiration.

Comment: I abandoned the Google libraries for the same reason.

Comment: In the last weeks have been working hard to provide a better OAuth2 experience. Most of the code is already in the repository, and there are several code reviews in the near future. In the next weeks we are going to release 1.6.0-beta, which will provide a better developer experience for working with OAuth2 both for WP, WinRT, MVC, .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 applications. We will improve the documentation as well. Sorry for the bad experience you had so far, but we are working on that... Feel free to open a new issue in our issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list.

Comment: @peleyal That's good news. In fairness, it was the Java library I abandoned, so perhaps the dotnet library is in better shape than its Java counterpart. I'm actually very happy doing my own Oauth,so would prob never switch back, but for the sake of those who may follow, there needs to be a rock-solid contract as part of the abstracted API; no guess work for the developer. It also needs to come out of Beta before I could use it in production (company policy).

Comment: We are aware of that. Thanks for the feedback @pinoyyid. I know that the OAuth2 experience is so bad right now. Hopefully it will be changed very soon. Thanks again.